# Draw NSTextField setting the content NSRect

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield, appkit

Given a struct `Concept` that has an associated `text: String` and `area: NSRect`, that when drawn on the view, it will draw the `String` in the given `NSRect`.

I would like to on click, **show a `NSTextField` which "content" (cell) NSRect is equal to the given NSRect**

If I tried to set up `textField.frame = concept.area`, the cell will be rendered in an inset position considering the border + padding of the `NSTextField`, so it will render the text in a different, slightly moved, NSRect.

In code the idea would be something like

```swift
struct Concept {
  let text: String
  let area: NSRect

  func draw() {
    text.draw(inRect: area)
  }
}

let conceptRect = NSRect(x: 50, y: 60, width: 80, height: 20)
let concept = Concept(text: "sample text", area: conceptRect)

let textField = NSTextField()
textField.stringValue = concept.text

textField.???? = area
let textFieldRect = textField.frame

assert(textFieldRect != conceptRect)
assert(textFieldRect.contains(conceptRect))
```

And the expected result should look like:

[image]

any ideas on how can I achieve this?

thanks

Comment: why not always use NSTextField and only change its editable/borders on click?

Comment: i'm experimenting on different approaches to implement this kind of view, in terms of resources i don't need multiple text fields, because always 1 will be active, not more, then i decided to use a common textfield that i just position where i draw my content.

Comment: Take a look at the [Sketch Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Sketch/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say how you're drawing the string in the `area`, which can affect exactly where it draws.

If you want to figure out what the text field's border padding is, you can compare its `cell`'s `drawingRect(forBounds:)` with the text field's `bounds`. The drawing rect will be inset by a bit from the bounds. To compute a frame to get a particular drawing rect, you reverse that by "outsetting" from the desired drawing rect by the same amount.